# How do I return a longitude and latitude from Google Maps JavaScript geocoder?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

When I use the code below its alerting a blank value? why is that?

HTML

```
<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="display()">
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var geocoder;
var map;


  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var loc=[];

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });

    return loc;
  }

  function display(){
     var long_lat=codeAddress();
    alert(long_lat);
  }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

because your function `codeAddress` is executed, assigning empty array to loc, executing asynchronous request to google geocoder and returns loc, which is empty, because its real value is assigned when response from google comes. In other words, allert should be inside response handler:

```
var geocoder;
var map;


  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var loc=[];

    // next line creates asynchronous request
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      // and this is function which processes response
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        alert( loc ); // the place where loc contains geocoded coordinates

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });

    // pretty meaningless, because it always will be []
    // this line is executed right after creating AJAX request, but not after its response comes
    return loc;
  }

  function display(){
     codeAddress();
  }
```

this is how  AJAX works... process results in callback handlers.

---

if you want to separate geocoding and 'dispalying' you can execute display function inside handler:

```
  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var loc=[]; // no need to define it in outer function now
        loc[0]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        display( loc ); 

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });

  }

  function display( long_lat ){
     alert(long_lat);
  }
```

html:

```
<input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

---

you can make it even more generic, if you will geocode not only to display. Then you can define callback as parameter to `codeAddress` function:

```
function codeAddress( callback ) {
...
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   ...
   callback( loc ); // instead of dispaly( loc );
   ...
 }
...
}

codeAddress( display ); // to execute geocoding
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,is there any way of returning those values to a variable? bcos i intend to use it in another function as a parameter

Comment: this still doesnt solve the problem i have got,i was planning to get the return values for mutiple postcode.basically i was trying to create a generic function where i can pass a postcode as an argument and get the long and lat values in return.since those values are in the call back i guess it cant be returned.

Comment: @manraj82: the only place where you would write `return loc;` could be anonymous function passed to `geocoder.geocode` function. this anonymous function is executed somewhere inside google scripts, by ajax response processors, so this information will never come to your code. AJAX works though callback executing, but not with returning values... It is out of your control